# Help manipulating a sum

Tags: derivatives, summation

Let
$S(x,t)=e^{2xt-t^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{H_n(x)}{n!}t^n$
If we now differentiate each term with respect to $x$ we find:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}=2tS&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}2\frac{H_n(x)}{n!}t^{n+1}
\\&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}2\frac{H_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!}t^{n}
\\&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}2\frac{H_n'(x)}{n!}t^{n}
\end{align*}

I cant see how the last step is done, turn the $H_{n-1}$ into a $H_n'(x)$? Any help would be great thankyou

Comment: $H_n'(x)=2nH_{n-1}(x)$ this is the result I want to get to but I cant see where the derivative springs up from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $S(x,t)= e^{xt-t^2}$. Thus it is easy to check that $\partial_x S= 2 t S$.

Now use the definition of $H_n(x)$,
$$ \tag{1} S(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x)}{n!} t^n.$$

Taking the derivative of (1) with respect to $x$, we have (exchanging the summation and differentiation)
$$ \tag{2} \partial_x S(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n'(x)}{n!} t^n.$$

Similarly, multiplying (1) by $2t$ yields
$$\tag{3} 2 t S(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2 H_n(x)}{n!} t^{n+1} =
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2 H_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!} t^{n} .$$

Now, we know that (2) should be equal to (3);
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n'(x)}{n!} t^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2 H_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!} t^{n}$$
for all $t$ which can only be true of each coefficient of $t^n$ matches;
$$ \frac{H_0'(x)}{0!} = 0 \Rightarrow H_0'(x)=0 $$
and
$$  \frac{H_n'(x)}{n!} = \frac{2 H_{n-1}(x)}{(n-1)!} \Rightarrow
 H_n'(x) =2 n H_{n-1}(x)$$
for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: That is excellent, Thank you very much :)